# Relative interior of a simple set

Tags: general-topology

What is the relative interior of $\mathbb{R}_{+}\times[0,1]$?
I need this to verify the conditions of a Theorem but unfortunately
don't know enough topology to figure it out myself. My guess would
be $(0,+\infty)\times(0,1)$? I'd appreciate an intuitive explanation.

Comment: If that's your guess, I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean with $\mathbb R^2_+$.

Comment: @StefanMesken Sorry that was a mistake. I mean $[0,+\infty)$

Comment: And apparently you didn't mean to write "$^2$". So, why don't you try to prove that your guess is correct? If it works, great. If you get stuck, that should give a hint where you may have gone wrong. Please also show your work and don't just say that you got stuck.

Comment: I didn't say I got stuck. My guess is based on: "the relative interior of a set contains all points which are not on the "edge" of the set, relative to the smallest subspace in which this set lies", from Wikipedia. As I said I don't have the technical background to prove my guess.

Comment: And yes, "^2" was the mistake which I've corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative interior of a subspace S is the subspace itself because every topology includes the whole space as an open set. The interior of the subset S itself can be different because the open sets are coming from the space of which S is a subset.

For example consider the subspace S = [0,1] of R.
The interior of the subset S is (0,1) while relative to S, it is S.